# iOS compile error: No visible @interface for 'CDViewController' declares the selector

Tags: ios, xcode

Since I switched my iOS project to ARC, I keep getting this compiler error:

> No visible @interface for 'CDViewController' declares the selector
>   'setUseAgof:'

In this line:

```
[self.viewController setUseAgof:false];
```

In this file:

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import <Cordova/CDVPlugin.h>
#import "NSString+MD5.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window, viewController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    // (...)
    [self.viewController setUseAgof:false]; // <-- HERE
    // (...)

    return YES;
}

@end
```

Although the method is definitely defined:

**MainViewController.h**

```
#import <Cordova/CDVViewController.h>
#import <ADTECHMobileSDK/ADTECHMobileSDK.h>

@interface MainViewController : CDVViewController <ATInterstitialViewDelegate>{
    ATInterstitialView *interstitial;
}
- (void)setUseAgof:(BOOL)useAgofParam;
@end

@interface MainCommandDelegate : CDVCommandDelegateImpl
@end

@interface MainCommandQueue : CDVCommandQueue
@end
```

**MainViewController.m**

```
#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController()
    - (void)setUseAgof:(BOOL)useAgofParam;
@end

@implementation MainViewController

BOOL useAgof = true;

- (void)setUseAgof:(BOOL)useAgofParam
{
    NSLog(@"1.) Setting useAgof = %d", (int)useAgofParam);
    useAgof = useAgofParam;
}
```

I don't get it. What's wrong?

---

**Update:**

**AppDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Cordova/CDVViewController.h>
#import <INFOnlineLibrary/INFOnlineLibrary.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>{}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIWindow* window;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet CDVViewController* viewController;

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`viewController` seems to be declared as pointer of `CDVViewController`. You are calling a method which is part of `MainViewController` the class derived from `CDVViewController`. Method being called is part of derived class and not the base class, hence make `viewController` pointer of  `MainViewController` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `viewController` property in your `AppDelegate` has a type of `CDVViewController *` rather than `UIViewController *`.

Comment: Looks good to me: `@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet CDVViewController* viewController;`

Comment: Should it be `MainViewController`? Since OP has declared the function in `MainViewController` interface.

Comment: @Timo The declared method is part of derived class and not the base class. Do you get the problem?

Comment: @Amar Damn, you're right! So, in AppDelegate.h it must be `@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet MainViewController* viewController;` - Thanks! If you post your suggestion as an answer, I'll gladly mark it as "the right answer".